Difficulty with Jupyter
I am experiencing difficulties with Jupyter Notebook. I encountered an issue where I can only see the blue cell outline. The green cell outline does not appear, and keyboard shortcuts such as Escape, Enter, A, B, and D are unresponsive.

How to resolve this?
I wanted to see the cell in green (editing mode) and the cell in blue (navigating mode).  I can only see the blue cell.
The Escape key and Enter key are not working for either.

Welcome to SO, @Manisha Tomar. Unfortunately, we cannot see your screenshots.

I see you have the Anaconda tag here. Is this a fresh installation of the Anaconda Distribution or did you only partially update something? It sounds like the latter. Depending on the age of your installation and how well you stuck to only using Anaconda/conda, things can be trickier to update cleanly.

In addition to @Sheldon's comment about the screenshots, it would also be useful to provide additional context that describes your setup.  There are many ways to set up and use Jupyter Notebook, it would be helpful to know things like OS, whether you're using a container, whether using Notebook via browser or some other tools like VSCode, etc.

@Sheldon  I just add the screenshot.

@wayne   Yes, It’s a fresh installation, after that I tried to open the Jupyter notebook and did not see the option to create Python notebook. So I followed the tutorial https://medium.com/@WamiqRaza/how-to-create-virtual-environment-jupyter-kernel-python-6836b50f4bf4 and installed the python & Jupyter without deleting anything pre existing.
Now, Jupyter is working and I can run python code in it but I do not see all the Blue and Green cell.

@teejay I am on windows 10 and using Jupyter in browser. I am pretty new to Python & Jupter.

What you show in your screenshot of the versions installed and what you link to have nothing to do with the Anaconda Distribution. So why the 'Anaconda3' tag?


Irrespective of color, are you able to type into the cell at all?  I just checked, and I don't get a green outline either.  The cell outline remains blue when I am editing.
How did you install and then run Jupyter notebook?  For e.g. I installed using pip install notebook at the command line within a Python virtual environment.


You mostly answered your own question when you added the screenshot showing you are using 7.0.8 according to your provided print out of jupyter --version.
Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on the same components as the modern JupyterLab, and so things are different. See additional notes and resources about this shift in the Jupyter ecosystem over the last few months in the bottom part of my answer here.
One of the differences is the color and how the cells react when in the 'Edit' mode vs. 'Command' mode. For example, when making JupyterLab, a lot of thought went into the indicators for the cells, see here, and they were deliberately chosen to be different than the classic interface and more consistent with the modern web experience.
Option A:
Get a feel for the new software.
Below I have a screenshot showing the current state of the Jupyter Notebook documentation from here. You can currently see the 'Migrating to Notebook 7' along the navigation bar now. Under there is introductory material for the current in-development Jupyter Notebook interface. What is stated there should match up with your experience now since you are using 7.0.8 according to your provided print out of jupyter --version!
Keep in mind that there is going to be differences. A lot of old screenshots and videos won't match up precisely with what you see. However, the newer JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ have more abilities and more ways to customize than the classic interface.
Option B:
Decide you want the older option.
You could get the classic look and feel with nbclassic mode. (I would suggest as a new user, as you indicate here, that would be ill-advised. That interface is not in current development and will progressively become less consistent with Jupyter as a whole as the development of JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ progress. That said, it is possible.)
If you want try the nbclassic flavor now without installing anything on your own system, go here and click on the 'launch binder' badge.
When the session comes up, you'll have a URL, something like this below, yet different in the specific combination of letters and digits in front of /tree:
https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/jtpio-35a72862c-31b61ebac2d9786-e5enffpe/tree

You'll leave your combination intact and replace the /tree at the end of the URL with /nbclassic and hit enter to go to that page. What will then load will be the classic interface of Jupyter notebook, specifically now called 'nbclassic'. You can make a new notebook and see the color highlights of the cells as you expect when you hit Esc, etc. The current documentation details this. (I'm pasting a screenshot of it for posterity only.)

I'm sure this documentation will get updated soon as Jupyter Notebook 7+ becomes the prevailing interface. (You can currently see the 'Migrating to Notebook 7' along the navigation bar now. Under there is introductory material for the current in-development Jupyter Notebook interface. What is stated there should match up with your experience now since you are using 7.0.8 according to your provided print out of jupyter --version!)

If you are using Anaconda/conda and want to install nbclassic, see here.
The page on nbclassic covers installing those not using the more full-featured Anaconda/conda package manager.
